# Kernel 4.16 and VirtualBox 5.2

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, 17.10

I recently updated my kernel to 4.16 in my Ubuntu mate 17.10.

I was aware of the possibility of issues with Virtual Box But now it's done I have an issue:

```
WARNING: The vboxdrv kernel module is not loaded. Either there is no module available for the current kernel (4.16.0-041600-generic) or it failed to load. Please recompile the kernel module and install it by
            sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

But when I did this he told me the same:

```
There were problems setting up Virtual Box. To re-start the set-up process, run: /sbin/vboxconfig
```

I tried to reinstall from .deb to ppa last updates but it remains the same.

If anyone has an idea ? Perhap's wait for an update ...

Comment: Try to rebuild virtualbox modules for your new kernel `sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup`

Comment: thx @Ali Razmdideh for the edit i want to learn how to post something that don't need to be edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my issue is resolved.

The reason why is that the tutorial to install kernel 4.16 only told me to install:

```
linux-image-4.16.0-041600-generic_4.16.0-041600.201804012230_amd64.deb
linux -headers-4.16.0-041600_4.16.0-041600.201804012230_all.deb
```

Virtualbox box missed :

```
linux-headers-4.16.0-041600-generic_4.16.0-041600.201804012230_amd64.deb
```

After that installed i could correctly did :

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

and it worked perfect:)

I try to install a new VM and an old OVA to tell you if it works correctly

Comment: The OVA could be perfectly installed all works perfect

Answer (score 1):

Next time try to install new kernels via `Ukuu` kernel manager which will does all your work automatically

https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: yes i know `Ukuu` i used it for a moment and updated kernel at every new release with not any issue.  Now i'm not sure, i read that ubuntu verified kernel are safer. But That LTS was too tempting to me ^^ I fall on that tutorial and it goes on :) I give you +1 because `Ukuu` is very great